# how to check date output for each day in a specified range in linux command

Tags: linux, shell

I have this command `date -d "-0 month -$(($(date +%d)-1)) days" +%Y%m%d`, and I like to know for all the days between 2014-Sep-1 and 2014-Sep-30, what the returned results will be.

How to simulate this without changing my system clock?

Comment: Your questions is unclear `what the returned results will be?`. Do you mean `for ((i=1;i<=30;i++)); do printf "2014-Sep-%s\n" "$i"; done` or do you mean what the code would look like to generate it? It's hard to tell whether `date` date is needed at all?

Comment: Sorry that I did not make it clearer. I meant to say that assuming TODAY is 2014-Sep-1, ..., 2014-Sep-30, respectively, and run the command `date -d "-0 month -$(($(date +%d)-1)) days" +%Y%m%d` as is, what results would I get back.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `-d` option for `date` again.

```
$ date -d "2014-09-01"
Mon Sep  1 00:00:00 CEST 2014
$ date -d "2014-09-01 + 1 day"
Tue Sep  2 00:00:00 CEST 2014
```

So something like

```sh
for i in `seq 0 29`
do
    today=$(date -d "2014-09-01 + $i days" '+%F')
    day=$(date -d "2014-09-01 + $i days" '+%-d')
    date -d "$today -0 month -$(($day - 1)) days" '+%Y%m%d'
done
```

should do the trick.  Note that I have changed the format specifier to `%-d`.  Otherwise, the shell will interpret the first nine value as octal, which will fail for 08 and 09.

However, I'm not quite sure what you are ultimately trying to achieve.  If you only want to print the first day in the month,

```
$ date '+%Y%m01'
```

seems *a lot* simpler.

Comment: Please see my comment. I am not asking what you wrote as is. Sorry for not making it clearer earlier.

Comment: I hope my edit makes it clearer.  The second command behaves as-if it was the day specified in the first command.

Comment: but the results are wrong. The expected result is the first day of the month's dates. :)

Comment: Ok, fixed.  But now it does not make any sense to me any more.  What are you actually trying to do?

Comment: I suspect the command I put up is not returning correctly the expected result, which is, the date of first day of every month. So I want to verify that. Does it make sense?

Comment: It does make sense to verify the command and indeed, it had the issue with octal numbers mentioned above.  However, the machinery to test has grown so unwieldy that it obscures the actual intent of the code and is more likely to introduce new bugs.  Just use `date '+%Y%m01'` and you'll be fine.  It is so simple that you can *see* it will be correct. ;-)